# Syntax highlighting in Microsoft Office Word

Tags: microsoft-word, syntax-highlighting, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I easily highlight the syntax of PHP code in Word?](https://superuser.com/questions/39571/how-do-i-easily-highlight-the-syntax-of-php-code-in-word)

I need to paste some code (ANSI C) in Microsoft Office Word, and I need some form of syntax highlighting (instead of simply changing the font to `Lucida Console`)

Is there some sort of addon maybe that will let me highlight code syntax in Microsoft Office Word ?

Comment: This was asked for PHP, solution is the same:
http://superuser.com/questions/39571/how-do-i-easily-highlight-the-syntax-of-php-code-in-word

Comment: @T. Kaltnekar: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: As a side note: you might want to disable the auto-change option that changes quotes into curly-quotes, and changes double-dashes into en/em-dashes. Otherwise just clicking in the code might actually change it...

Comment: This is also a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/169010/word-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 58, accepted):

*Taken from [Breakthrough's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/39571/how-do-i-easily-highlight-the-syntax-of-php-code-in-word/39600#39600) for [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/39571/how-do-i-easily-highlight-the-syntax-of-php-code-in-word)* (*thanks to [T. Kaltnekar](https://superuser.com/users/6682/t-kaltnekar)'s comment*)

---

You can use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) to accomplish this in three ways. Just so you know, Notepad++ is a more advanced version of Notepad, which supports syntax highlighting of different code files "out of the box" - PHP included!

Download & install it, fire it up, and load up your PHP file. You should automatically see it beautifully coloured (if not, because the file extension is something other than `.php`, go to Language -> PHP or Language -> P -> PHP).

If you need to change any of the colours, you can easily do so - just go to Settings -> Styler Configurator. From that menu, you can change the various highlighting and font options, to suit your needs - although the default usually suffices for most.

Then, go to Plugins -> NppExport. From there, you have three options you can consider:

- Export to RTF
- Export to HTML
- Copy all formats to clipboard

Start with the last one - "Copy all formats to clipboard" - which will copy the entire file *with the highlighted syntax* to the clipboard. Once you click it, then open Microsoft Word, and just hit paste! You should see the beautifully syntax-highlighted code. If something goes wrong, then you can try one of the other options (export to RTF/HTML), although I've never had a problem with the clipboard method.

Comment: Love it! I even mapped this command to 'CTRL+SHIFT+C' keystroke. Makes it so easy to put colored code samples into an email!

Comment: This also works from VS Code. Just copy like normal and when you paste it will include your theme and colours.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) to export code to .rtf or .html and then use that in your document.

I have tried different Office plugins but they never worked nicely. Or I didn't find one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any Office plugins that will do this, but if you have Visual Studio or Visual C++ Express Edition installed, you can copy and paste code (that will keep its formatting) from Visual Studio directly into Word.