# Word Syntax Highlighting

Tags: microsoft-word, syntax-highlighting, publishing

I'm writing an article and I would to maintain notepad++ syntax highlight when I paste a code block into word. The code is all in SQL, and I would very much like to the way it is formatted.

Also, print-screen and cut/paste the images is NOT an option.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do not use the `not-programming-related` tag. If you feel the need to use it, your question does not belong here. If the question *does* belong here, then the tag isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jeez.eu/2009/09/09/great-and-necessary-plugins-for-notepad-plus-plus/

Check out the section on NppExport.  Seems to be what you're looking for ("Copy as RTF")

Comment: worked like a charm!

Comment: The link in the original answer does not work anymore, but the NppExport plugin can be found here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/NppExport/

Answer (score 2):

It happens to be the case that NppExport ships with notepad++. Check your Plugins -> NppExport menu for options to copy RTF snippets to the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio, for C# code (so, and, I assume for SQL), will include HTML formatting when copy'n'pasting code into something which understands HTML.

Comment: Another option is to use a general-purpose syntax highlighter like Pygment or GeSHi to convert a piece of source code into HTML markup. Then you can similarly copy and paste the highlighted code into any type of word processor that understands HTML.