# Convert Large HTML to DOC?

Tags: conversion, html, documents

I am programmatically converting an existing HTML file that has been dynamically created to a MS Word document. I've ran into a situation where the MS Word Document object fails to process the HTML file if that file ends up being very large. I get the same result irrespective of my choice of programming language (I've tried converting from HTML to DOC in C++ and VBScript). I also see that even the Microsoft Word application chokes up while trying open this same file.

I thought of eliminating the task of dynamically generating a HTML file and instead write its contents into a *.doc file. But there's the issue of preserving previously defined formatting and layout.

Is anyone able to walkthrough additional options?

Answer (score 0):

First off, the following requires Notepad++ and its NppExport plugin. If you don't have it, you won't regret installing it. You can get Notepad++ [here](http://www.filehippo.com/download_notepad/). The NppExport plugin can be obtained through the (Plugins -> Plugin Manager) option in Notepad++.

Now once you have it you could just go ahead and open the source file in Notepad++ and do [this](https://superuser.com/questions/60760/syntax-highlighting-in-microsoft-office-word).

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have a license to Aspose.NET libraries. I ended up using that. It's a shame I wasn't able to the Microsoft.Word object.