# How to make syntax highlighting for source code in Outlook 2007 email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Syntax highlighting in Microsoft Office Word](https://superuser.com/questions/60760/syntax-highlighting-in-microsoft-office-word)
>   [How do I easily highlight the syntax of PHP code in Word?](https://superuser.com/questions/39571/how-do-i-easily-highlight-the-syntax-of-php-code-in-word)

When I send email to someone with source snippet then how to format source code like this type. with line number

[image]

Comment: see: http://superuser.com/questions/60760/syntax-highlighting-in-microsoft-office-word (as word is normally used as the editor for outlook mail...)

Answer (score 3):

Some text editors will let you copy syntax-colored text as HTML. [Editplus](http://editplus.com/) is one, using the menu Edit -> Clipboard -> Copy as HTML. It doesn't do line numbers though.

Comment: Vim and emacs can do this also.  In vim you use :tohtml, in emacs, use the htmlize package.

Comment: Notepad++ offers the functionality to insert line numbers into the text in an additional step. Maybe Editplus can do the same.