# How can I copy text with syntax-highlighting from Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, copy-paste, syntax-highlighting

I have an XML snippet in Notepad++ that I would like to share with a co-worker via email. In Notepad++ the syntax highlighting nicely shows off the elements and attributes. Here is a sample picture:

[image: XML]

When I copy/paste this in Outlook only the text comes over. The Outlook email is set to HTML. I have also verified in Word only the text is pasted.

There are separate `Copy to Clipboard` menu items but they look focused on filenames. Is there an option or extension that will copy the formatting as well as the text?

Comment: Possible duplicates http://superuser.com/questions/125210/how-to-make-syntax-highlighting-for-source-code-in-outlook-2007-email, http://superuser.com/questions/60760/syntax-highlighting-in-microsoft-office-word, http://superuser.com/questions/39571/how-do-i-easily-highlight-the-syntax-of-php-code-in-word  The solution seems to be to use `Plugins > NppExport`

Comment: @ernie Doh and I have NppExport installed and searched for an answer here first. Thanks you can add as an answer and I will accept

Comment: Though this question is marked as duplicate of the original PHP question, I find it more relatable with my need as a Notepad++ user.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Copy and paste of [Breakthrough's answer for a similar question](https://superuser.com/a/39600/85121):

You can use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) to accomplish this in three ways.  Just so you know, Notepad++ is a more advanced version of Notepad, which supports syntax highlighting of different code files "out of the box" - PHP included!

Download & install it, fire it up, and load up your PHP file.  You should automatically see it beautifully coloured (if not, because the file extension is something other than `.php`, go to Language -> PHP or Language -> P -> PHP).

If you need to change any of the colours, you can easily do so - just go to Settings -> Styler Configurator.  From that menu, you can change the various highlighting and font options, to suit your needs - although the default usually suffices for most.

Then, go to Plugins -> NppExport.  From there, you have three options you can consider:

- Export to RTF
- Export to HTML
- Copy all formats to clipboard

Start with the last one - "Copy all formats to clipboard" - which will copy the entire file *with the highlighted syntax* to the clipboard.  Once you click it, then open Microsoft Word, and just hit paste!  You should see the beautifully syntax-highlighted code.  If something goes wrong, then you can try one of the other options (export to RTF/HTML), although I've never had a problem with the clipboard method.

Possible duplicates [How to make syntax highlighting for source code in Outlook 2007 email?](https://superuser.com/questions/125210/how-to-make-syntax-highlighting-for-source-code-in-outlook-2007-email), [Syntax highlighting in Microsoft Office Word](https://superuser.com/questions/60760/syntax-highlighting-in-microsoft-office-word), [How do I easily highlight the syntax of PHP code in Word?](https://superuser.com/questions/39571/how-do-i-easily-highlight-the-syntax-of-php-code-in-word)

Comment: In Notepad++ v7.7.1, NppExport maintains font name, size, and bold, but not font color. Works fine in 7.6.x. See: [NppExport plugin - 'copy HTML to clipboard' does not work anymore](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17716/nppexport-plugin-copy-html-to-clipboard-does-not-work-anymore)