# Notepad++ Copy text with Syntax highlighting does not work

Tags: microsoft-word, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I copy HTML text with syntax highlighting in Notepad++

[image: coping HTML text with syntax highlighting in Notepad++]

Then I insert it into the MS Word, taking into account the formatting inserting HTML text with syntax highlighting into the MS Word, taking into account the formatting

[image: inserting HTML text with syntax highlighting into the MS Word, taking into account the formatting]

As a result, the text does not have syntax highlighting text does not have syntax highlighting

[image: text does not have syntax highlighting]

What could be the reason? I have already reinstalled Notepad ++, returned the default settings to it, but nothing helps. Although it used to work. What could be the cause of the malfunction?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there're no syntax highlighting in a word document.

"Keep source formatting" keeps format, not syntax highlighting

Comment: No!
The issue has been reported on the Notepad++ bug tracker and is due to the fact that the plug-in NPP Export 0.2.8 doesn't work in version 7.7.

The corresponding issue with the plug-in has since been fixed, but (as of this writing) the new release, version 0.2.9.21, is not yet available through Notepad++'s built-in plug-in manager, which still lists version 0.2.8.

A work-around is to downgrade Notepad++ to an older version, pre 7.7.
More -> https://superuser.com/questions/1444697/syntax-highlighting-not-retained-when-pasting-from-notepad-into-word?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Cool, this problem is solved!

More this -> [Syntax highlighting not retained when pasting from Notepad++ into Word](https://superuser.com/questions/1444697/syntax-highlighting-not-retained-when-pasting-from-notepad-into-word?rq=1)

It turns out that notepad version 7.7 and above does not support copying text with syntax highlighting. You need to install an earlier version, for example, I installed version 7.6.6 and it works!
[copy text with syntax highlighting in Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc2JX.jpg)

[with syntax highlighting into the MS Word, taking into account the formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U79En.jpg)

[text does not have syntax highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX9Lo.jpg)